# Problem with the Bernoulli's equation for fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

Suppose we have a $U$ shaped hollow tube consisting of three parts as : $T_{v1}$, $T_{v2}$, and $T_{h}$ , representing two vertical tubes and one horizontal tube respectively. The configuration is kept fixed as such so that the horizontal tube acts as a base. Let $T_{v1}$ have a cross-sectional area $A$ and $T_{v2}$ have cross-sectional area $2A$ *(The horizontal tube may have any small finite cross-sectional area)*. An ideal fluid is placed in the tube which starts executing a periodic motion **(I'm not sure if this would be simple harmonic motion or not)**. Assume at a certain instant $h_1 >h_2$ and that the liquid is flowing from $T_{v1}$ to $T_{v2}$.    Now I apply Bernoulli's equation at the two liquid surfaces in $T_{v1}$ and $T_{v2}$. 
$$P_{atm} + 1/2{\rho}v_1^2 + {\rho}gh_1=P_{atm} +1/2{\rho} v_2^2 +{\rho}gh_2$$
Using equation of continuity $$v_1=2v_2$$ 
This would lead to 
$$3/2{\rho}v_2^2= {\rho}g(h_2 - h_1)$$
This gives me a complex solution for velocity. How is this possible? Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem here is that you cannot use Bernoulli's principle in this problem because the fluid motion is not steady. I think [this document](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/utube_osc.pdf) will help you. You could try to do the calculations as shown there, by using Newton's second law.

Comment: So what's making the motion unsteady? I mean is there a change in velocity as time passes or is it the break in the streamlines?

Comment: You would expect the system to oscillate, because $h_1 \neq h_2$, so velocity is not constant. You need to take into account the temporal dependence, so you would have to solve a differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you cannot assume at a certain time $h_{1} > h_{2}$! How did you assume this condition?! I mean you don't know the height of fluid column in $T_{v1}$ and $T_{v2}$. In fact, the only thing you know certainly is that $v_{1} = 2v_{2}$ then we have:

$$\frac{1}{2} \rho v_{1}^{2} + \rho g h_{1} = \frac{1}{2} \rho v_{2}^{2} + \rho g h_{2}$$

or:

$$\frac{1}{2} \rho v_{2}^{2} + \rho g h_{2} = \frac{1}{2} \rho 4v_{2}^{2} + \rho g h_{1}$$

or again:

$$\frac{3}{2} \rho v_{2}^{2} = \rho g (h_{2} - h_{1})$$

or furthermore:

$$h_{2} - h_{1} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{v_{2}^{2}}{g}$$

So the only thing you could say that $h_{2} > h_{1}$ and that's the reason why your solution was incorrect. Note that you can always calculate the height difference $h_{2} - h_{1}$ not their absolute values because height also needs reference like pressure.

Also for those who suggested to use unsteady Bernoulli equation! Such a nice invention!? I mean there is not time-dependent or steady Bernoulli equation. Bernoulli equation is just energy balance and as long as there are no non-conservative forces should work no matter the flow is steady or unsteady!

Comment: Let's say I use disk that can push fluid down in vertical tube $2$ so that $h_1>h_2$. Then I quickly remove this disk so that fluid starts flowing from $1$ to $2$. This is how you can assume what you some reason have dismissed.

Comment: Also, there is no point in redoing the math already preformed in the question.

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes, you can push the fluid with whatever you want, but the relation $v_{1} = 2 v_{2}$ is not hold true anymore and that's the thing you dismissed! In fact, $v_{2} > v_{1}$ when you push it. But when you remove the pushing force (i.e. your disk), the fluid will back to its equilibrium and again ($v_{1} = 2 v_{2}$) and same story as before!

Comment: Also, in the question, he tried to calculate velocity from heights by assuming a wrong assumption! But. here I'm trying to say you can't simply assume that $h_{1} > h_{2}$. The mass conservation equation $v_{1} = 2v_{2}$ implies that it should be $h_{2} > h_{1}$ and you can't assume anything else!

Comment: I am talking about after you remove the disk. $v_1=2v_2$ holds at all times after this, not just when $h_2>h_1$. From your answer you make it seem like $h_1>h_2$ is impossible, which is not true. Your answer cannot handle the scenario when we start the fluid with $h_1>h_2$ which is a valid initial condition.

Comment: I don't say that $h_{1} > h_{2}$ is impossible but I'm trying to say if $h_{2} > h_{1}$ the relation $v_{1} = 2 v_{2}$ could be valid relation and if $h_{1} > h_{2}$ the relation $v_{1} = 2 v_{2}$ is not hold true anymore because it will lead to contradiction. I mean there is no doubt about Bernoulli equation and it should work at all times no matter the fluid is in the steady or unsteady condition. If you want to study the fluid when $h_{1} > h_{2}$  is hold true you should find other relation for the velocities at points 1 and 2.

Comment: By the way you could think of $h_{1} - h_{2}$ as a pressure gradient. When $h_{2} > h_{1}$ you should have $v_{1} > v_{2}$ and when $h_{1} > h_{2}$ you should have $v_{2} > v_{1}$. I mean you can't assume $h_{1} > h_{2}$ and $v_{1} > v_{2}$! That's the reason why the Bernoulli equation gives imaginary solution because this situation to have $h_{1} > h_{2}$ and $v_{1} > v_{2}$ simultaneously is physically impossible.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but I do not think it is correct. $|v_1|=2|v_2|$ is true always. It is, as you say, mass conservation. It is true no matter how the heights relate.

Comment: Others are correct in saying you need a modified form of Bernoulli's equation. A google search will help you to see this.

Comment: @AaronStevens According to Euler's equation there is another term as acceleration in the Bernoulli equation as: $\rho \frac{d v}{d t} \Delta x$. But in this case the problem will reach a complexity level which cannot be approached with elementary fluid dynamics knowledge. In fact even the acceleration term is not accurate because the true one is: $\int_{\Gamma} \rho \frac{\partial \mathbf{u} (\mathbf{r},t)}{\partial t} \cdot d\mathbf{l}$ where $\Gamma$ is the path which connects point 1 and 2 and $d\mathbf{l}$ is the differential form of the path. I think it needs numerical methods to solve!

Comment: I think the error in this "solution" becomes apparent if the vertical pipes have the same area. Then you have to conclude that $h_1=h_2$, which is not certainly true at all times.

Comment: That's an another story when you have a perfect straight pipe ($A_{1} = A_{2}$) your fluid could not be accelerated $v_{1} = v_{2}$. But obviously that's not true because still we could have acceleration even in a perfect pipe.

Comment: But the pipes aren't straight here. How do you explain how your solution method handles this?

Comment: I know it's not straight obviously since $v_{1} = 2 v_{2}$. I just add something to your previous comment. My solution is correct as long as velocity does not have any time-dependency ($\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t} = 0$). Otherwise this model would not work at all and we need to solve Euler's equation with appropriate boundary conditions.

Comment: But the problem is dealing with oscillations in the water levels, so you have just said your solution does not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for when there are acceleration, we could solve this problem like this:

$$\int_{1}^{2} \rho \frac{d v}{d t} dl + \frac{1}{2}\rho v_{2}^{2} + \rho g h_{2} = \frac{1}{2} \rho v_{1}^{2} + \rho g h_{1}$$

Let's say the path between 1 and 2 includes three parts as $1 \rightarrow 3$, $3 \rightarrow 4$, and $4 \rightarrow 2$. In part $1 \rightarrow 3$ the velocity is $v_{1}$, in the path $3 \rightarrow 4$ if the cross section is $A_{34}$ and its length is $L_{34}$, then velocity is $v_{34} = \frac{A}{A_{34}}v_{1}$. In the path $4 \rightarrow 2$ the velocity is $v_{2}$. So the integral would be expanded as:

$$\int_{1}^{2} \rho \frac{d v}{d t} dl = \int_{1}^{3} \rho \frac{d v}{d t} dl + \int_{3}^{4} \rho \frac{d v}{d t} dl + \int_{4}^{2} \rho \frac{d v}{d t} dl = \rho \frac{d v_{1}}{d t} h_{1} + \rho \frac{d v_{1}}{d t}\frac{A}{A_{34}}L_{34} + \rho \frac{d v_{2}}{d t}h_{2}$$

Also, we know that $\frac{1}{2}v_{1} = v_{2}$, so:

$$\int_{1}^{2} \rho \frac{d v}{d t} dl = \rho \frac{d v_{1}}{d t} h_{1} + \rho \frac{d v_{1}}{d t}\frac{A}{A_{34}}L_{34} + \frac{1}{2}\rho \frac{d v_{1}}{d t}h_{2}$$

Finally:

$$\rho \frac{d v_{1}}{d t} h_{1} + \rho \frac{d v_{1}}{d t}\frac{A}{A_{34}}L_{34} + \frac{1}{2}\rho \frac{d v_{1}}{d t}h_{2} + \frac{1}{4} \rho v_{1}^{2} + \rho g h_{2} = \frac{1}{2} \rho v_{1}^{2} + \rho g h_{1} $$

If we take: $a = h_{1} + \frac{A}{A_{34}} L_{34} + \frac{1}{2}h_{2}$, then:

$$a \frac{d v_{1}}{d t} = \frac{1}{4} v_{1}^{2} + g (h_{1}-h_{2})$$

Then by solving this ODE, we have:

$$v_{1}(t) = 2\sqrt{g (h_{1}-h_{2})} \tanh\Big(\frac{t}{\tau}\Big)$$

Where the relaxation time is defined as: $$\tau = \frac{a}{\sqrt{g (h_{1}-h_{2})}}$$

Comment: I am sorry, I don't mean to be picking on you, I just want the right answer to be posted. Shouldn't the solution be oscillatory? Also, what exactly is $h_1$ and $h_2$ in this solution? If they are the height of the water in each tube, then $h_1$ and $h_2$ also depend on time.